# Defining numerous variables in a single step?

Tags: javascript

Is there a solution I can use that allows me to define more than one var with the same value in a single step at the start of my funcion?

```
function myFunction () {
    var a,b = 0;
    document.write(a) // undefined
    document.write(b) // 0
}
```

Is there an improved way to write  `a,b = 0;` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this, however I don't like it.

```
var var1 = "hello",
    var2 = "world",
    var3 = 666;
```

Better

```
var var1 = "hello";
var var2 = "world";
var var3 = 666;
```

Please take a look at http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: I like Crockford, I really do, but whether it is better or not is completely subjective, especially the nonsense suggestion of alphabetically ordering the declarations.

Comment: I agree, it's subjective. I presume the reader won't take everything I say, Crockford or anyone for that matter as gospel, but naturally form his/her own opinion.

Comment: Are you kidding? This is the world of jQuery.  Of course novices will take what Crockford says as gospel ... as soon as they figure out who he is.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do two things at once. You can't declare multiple local variables and assign a single value to all of them at the same time.  You can do either of the following

```
var a = 1, 
    b = 1;
```

or

```
var a,b;
a = b = 1;
```

What you don't want to do is

```
var a = b = 1;
```

because you'll end up with `b` being a global, and that's no good.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = 0, b = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = 0, b = a;
```

Answer (score -1):

An alternate way

```
var a = b = 0;
```

Comment: Same problem as the answer by sAc